# Apply function at level 1 and the operator @@@

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a confusion with the Apply function. The Apply function replaces the head of an expression at the desired level. For example:

```
In[124]:= Apply[Superscript, {{2, 3}}, {1}]

Out[124]= {Superscript[2,3]}
```

On the other hand the operator @@@ is equivalent to Apply acting at level {1} :

```
In[125]:= Superscript @@@ {{2, 3}}

Out[125]= {Superscript[2,3]}
```

However the level {1} of the expression is not an argument for Superscript:

```
In[126]:= Level[{{2, 3}}, {1}]

Out[126]= {{2, 3}}

In[127]:= FullForm[%]

Out[127]=List[List[2,3]]
```

Since :

```
In[131]:= Superscript[List[2, 3]]

Out[131]= Superscript[{2, 3}]
```

So it is as if the operator @@@ is acting at level {2}

```
In[129]:= Level[{{2, 3}}, {2}]

Out[129]= {2, 3}

In[130]:= FullForm[%]

Out[130]=List[2,3]
```

and so replacing the head in the last expression is the same as :

```
In[132]:= Superscript[2, 3]

Out[132]= Superscript[2,3]
```

What is happening here?

Comment: `Level` returns a list. Try `Level[x[{1, 2}], {1}]` to understand.

Comment: "Apply replaces head**s** in parts of expr specified by levelspec" not "replaces the head of an expression".  So it relaces heads in each of expressions in `Level[{{2, 3}}, {1}]` as it returns a list by default. Perhaps using different heads will be clearer

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thankx!, I now understand my confusion: I was not interpreting correctly the output of Level, which is always a list.

Comment: @Kuba: thankx !